# VBA Word, get distinct count of each distinct array value

Tags: vba, ms-word

using VBA within MS Word. i have a group of numbers currently in an ArrayList (please recommend a better option to store a list of values) I want to get the distinct count of each value (so 10 =1 and 10.5 = 4).  I tried to filter the ArrayList but i dont think it does an exact match to the value just a 'contains', so filtering the array and counting didnt work for me (all values returned). i tried these other solution i found but couldnt get it to work. anyone recommend a solution.

sample data: 10, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5

```
arr = myarrayList.toarray
filteredArray = Filter(arr, 10, True, vbTextCompare) // does not filter, since all values 'contain' 10

count10 = Application.Count(Application.Match(arr, Array(10), 0)) //i dont think vba has Match 

occurrences = arr.lastIndexOf(10) - arr.IndexOf(10, 0) + 1  //i dont think vba has lastIndexof
```

Comment: Try putting the array elements in a `Ditionary'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub filterArray()
   Dim arr, dict As Object, El
   'to exemplify, I build the array as:
   arr = Split("10, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5", ", ")
   'you should use the array extracted from your ArrayList...

   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   For Each El In arr
        If Not dict.Exists(El) Then
            dict.Add El, 1
        Else
            dict(El) = dict(El) + 1
        End If
   Next
   Debug.Print dict(CStr(10))     'the dictionary keys are strings...
   Debug.Print dict(CStr(10.5))
End Sub
```

**Edited:**

Please, try the next version using integers (in the array and like dictionary keys):

```
Sub filterArrayX()
   Dim arr, dict As Object, El
   arr = Array(10, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5, 10.5)
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   For Each El In arr
        If Not dict.Exists(El) Then
            dict.Add El, 1
        Else
            dict(El) = dict(El) + 1
        End If
   Next
   Debug.Print dict(10)   
   Debug.Print dict(10.5)
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks. as is it works. but if i remove the "" and ending ",", it fails.  Why the " " and Split() and empty "," at end. my values dont come in like that they come in as integers.  thanks for any explanation to tweak your solution

Comment: @jon rios: I am afraid you do not understand the `Split` function... It splits a string on a specific separator. In this specific case, on ", " string. I only build the array in that way, using the pseudo string you posted. But the dictionary works in the same way with integers. I converted the keys because of that way of building the array. I will post a variant accepting integers...

Comment: thanks v2 works like a charm. thanks again for the follow up

Comment: @jon rios: Glad I could help!